# Is there a version of Wine that actually runs mainstream chat clients?

Tags: linux, wine, camera

Is there a version of Wine that actually runs mainstream chat clients? I'm willing to consider commercial forks. I'd need it to support at least:

- Yahoo
- QQ
- Skype (yes there's a native client but it's too outdated)

all with full voice and video support. Supporting more would be nice too.

Unfortunately all versions of Wine I've tried have either completely failed to run QQ, or botched the character encoding badly, showing Chinese correctly in some places and interpreting it as Latin-1 in other places, and I haven't gotten webcam/video chat support to work anywhere.

Is this just hopeless?

Comment: Using wine is a bit dicey. But what's wrong with Pidgin and the Linux version of Skype?

Comment: @Keith He did say Skype for Linux was too old.  A quick check myself shows Skype at 2.2 as a Beta for Linux from Skypes official website.  Skype for Windows is at 5.3.

Comment: @penguin Ah, that's right. But Pidgin works great for the text only services. How about [ekiga, or linphone](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Which_programs_work_with_Ekiga_%3F#Can_I_connect_to_a_SIP_server_with_Skype.3F)? True it doesn't work with Skype, but skype is proprietery and IMHO should not be on the Internet.

Comment: @Keith I never said I agreed with his approach, but I can understanding preferring Skype over Wine if the Linux version is so under maintained.  Personally, I push using Ekiga or Empathy for VoIP on Linux.  In fact, I use PSI or Empathy with XMPP Transports to connect to legacy networks like MSN instead of running Pidgin to natively connect just so I can at least claim partial use of an open chat protocol.

Comment: @penguin I understand. It may be worth trying to get skype working with Wine myself. :-o

Comment: Also, it may not be right to compare version numbers for different platforms. On Linux Skype is version 2.2, but that version number is for the Linux version. As long as it interoperates with version X on other platforms it should be fine.

Comment: @Keith Checking Wikipedia, Skype 2.0 was release for Linux in 2008, Skype 5.0 was released for Windows and Mac OS in 2010.  Skype is also at version 5.0+ for Symbian.  I wouldn't be surprised if there was a number of missing features in the Linux version.  Though, I do realize version numbers can be irrelevant when talking across operating systems.

Comment: I don't like depending on proprietary junk either, but I have clients who need it an the alternative would be running complete Windows systems (and having to maintain them). This question is not about choosing an ideal voice/video over IP system, but about working within existing requirements. :-(

Comment: @penguin FYI, [skype 2.2 for Linux](http://blogs.skype.com/garage/2011/04/skype_22_beta_for_linux_with_s.html) (beta, of course) was released just a few weeks ago.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't change the fact that the interface is horribly outdated and complete unfamiliar to the people who would be using it (and asking why they can't find any of the features they're used to). Also video support on the other networks I asked about is important.

Comment: @R.. That's why I mentioned Empathy.  It can do Voice and Video over XMPP and is compatible with other XMPP clients including Google Talk.  I can do Video chat on Empathy with someone else using GTalk from their web browser.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. It may be a good choice for Google Talk, but it definitely won't solve the QQ or Skype problem.